# How can I solve the NetBeans problem on the installation screen?

Tags: netbeans, java-11

When I try to install NetBeans I am left with the following loading screen.

[image: Error]

Details :
Windows v11, JDK v11, NetBeans v19

I deleted NetBeans, restarted my laptop, and tried to install another version of NetBeans but it always was stuck at 10% during the install.

Comment: There is an open NetBeans bug report for this issue. See [Cinfiguring the installer 10% #6338](https://github.com/apache/netbeans/issues/6338). A workaround is to not use the installer to install NetBeans, and instead [download and unzip the file **netbeans-19-bin.zip**](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb19/). Alternatively, you could use one of the  [**Community Installers**, as described in the Release Notes for NetBeans 19](https://netbeans.apache.org/download/nb19/), though they seem to bundle JDK 20 rather than JDK 11.

Comment: Thanks, well I was trying everything and it turns out that to install it I needed jdk 8, after that the already installed netbeans asked me for jdk 11 and I changed it and now everything is perfect. I will also try the teacher who recommends me since it seems very strange to me.

Comment: OK. To be clear, are you saying that the NetBeans 19 Installer won't work with JDK 11, but does work with JDK 8? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: No . To install I need version 8 after this when I run netbeans it necessarily asked me to use jdk version 11 or higher

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you saying that to resolve the problem in your screen shot (_"stuck at 10%"_) and install NetBeans you had to use JDK 8? If so, I find that surprising since NetBeans 19 itself does not support JDK 8.

Comment: I'm also confused, but since I couldn't find a solution I tried that and it did let me install but remember jdk 8 it only let me use it for the installation and when opening netbeans it did ask me for jdk 11 or higher